# C# ASP.NET MVC: develop app with running tasks and ASP.NET MVC web UI to control/monitor it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, service

I'm going to develop an application which is in charge of running tasks which may take several days.

I want to develop a web application as UI for it.

This web application is in charge of starting/stopping/pausing tasks and also it should report the progress of task whenever I login back to the application.

I already developed many desktop / ASP.NET MVC web applications however I have no idea which .NET component or technology should be used for developing such application.

I guess my application should be composed of two main components:

1. The part which is running long-running tasks (may something like a service and I don't know how services are implemented in C#).
2. A web-UI which binds to this services and control/monitor its activity.

I would be grateful if you can suggest the components which can manage this requirement.

Comment: You mean services running on your web serwer?

Comment: @Adlorem I have a windows server that can host apps, services and webserver to run web apps.